# How do I index referenceClass objects?

Tags: r, reference-class

So trying to use referenceClasses for the first time. I figured out how to create an object, but I want an "array" of objects.  I usually use data.frames but you can't put an object in a data frame.  trying to use lists, but can't figure it out.  Like this:

```
Stock <- setRefClass("Stock",
    fields = list(      
        symbol = "character",
        expArray = "data.frame",
        quote = "numeric",
        ))
```

## to create an object:

```
validExp <-c("131108","131115","131122","131129","131206","131221","140118","140719","150117")
validStocks <- c("AAPL", "TSLA","GOOG","HLF")

expArray <- data.frame(exp = validExp)
aStock <- Stock(symbol = "GOOG", expArray = expArray, quote=0)
```

which works fine.  But now how to I get an "array" of Stock objects indexed by validStocks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out exactly what you want, for example, what does:

```
expArray = expArray = expArray
```

mean? If you want an "array" of valid stocks, why not just create a list of reference objects

```
l = list(4)
l[["AAPL"]] = aStock
```